# Restore default navigation bar appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm making an iOS app for iPhone, and I'm using a navigation controller. At some point during the navigation, I'm adding a `UISegmentedControl` to a view controller, just under the navigation bar from the navigation controller. I'm inserting new background and shadow images in the navigation bar, to make the `UISegmentedControl` appear as part of the navigation bar. I do it like this:

```
    // nav bar color image
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, 0.5)          // Used in navBar, size dosn't matter
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0)
    barBackgroundColor.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let navBarBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // setup navbar
    navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarBackground, forBarMetrics: .Default)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

When I navigate away from that given view controller, the navigation bars background is still changed.

**How can I restore the navigation bars appearance?**

Or...

**Is there another way embed the `UISegmentedControl` into an expanded navigation bar?**

Image of navigation bar with custom background and Segmented Control below:
[image: Navbar with custom background. plus segment control below]

When navigating back, the navigation bar cuntinues to be custom:
[image]

**EDIT:**

In a view controller before i change the background images, i try to safe the standart image:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if sharedVariables.standartNavBarBackgroundImage == nil {
        let herp = navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundImageForBarMetrics(.Default)
        sharedVariables.standartNavBarBackgroundImage = herp
        let derp = navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage
        sharedVariables.standartNavBarShadowImage = derp
    }
}
```

Both `herp` and `derp` are `nil` after being set, dispite the navigationbar is visible at this momont. How come?

Comment: Show a picture of the end result you're looking for and what it looks like if you don't change the images

Comment: Images added..The end result should be the standart navigation bar appearance..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should be able to get the default appearance back just by setting the background image and shadow image to `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

With iOS 11.* and Swift 4, you need to set the `barTintColor` to `nil`.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
```

Comment: Not if it hasn't been changed before.