# Toggle navigation bar background image/color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

One of the scenes in my app should have transparent navigation bar, others — not.

So, when entering the scene, I'm trying to get current navbar's properties and restore them on exit.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    navigationBarBackgroundImage = [self.navigationController.navigationBar backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    navigationBarShadowImage = self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = navigationBarShadowImage;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Suddenly, it stopped working... Now, I'm getting NULLs for background and shadow images.

So, how can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

So, this question turned out to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141366/restore-default-navigation-bar-appearance).

I still can't understand why navigation bar is not restoring from view controller...

I'm just making all decoration things in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method of the UINavigationControllerDelegate.